# Load Resistance

Tags: amplifier, resistors, load

Suppose we have this circuit (I do not include bias):

[image]

using this model:

[image]

What's the difference between having:

1)  \$R = \frac {V_ {CC}} {I_C} \$

2) \$R = r_0\$

\$I_C\$ is the collector polarization current.

I would say: 1) maximum linear dynamics and 2) maximum power transfer.

It's wrong?

Comment: The schematic as drawn is nonsensical as the emmiter and collector are both grounded.

Comment: The collector is not grounded.